# Finding function through a graph

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, arithmetic

[image]

My understanding about checking if the function value lies on the graph is putting the x value and checking if it lies on the graph. Now in this example I'm a bit confused, when I solve a b and c, a gives function which will cover values greater than 1, and c will do the reverse. I think b option will cover the values in both + and -ve x axis. Am I interpreting it correctly?

Comment: Note that $f(0) = 0$, which of the options satisfy this constraint?

Comment: @caverac none of these first 3 options are satisfying this condition!? then?

Comment: $(B)$ clearly satisfies that.

Comment: Yes, one of them does. What I mean is, when you evaluate the function at $x = 0$, the result should be $0$

Comment: Option $(B)$ is what is known as a piecewise function (really just an absolute value function in this case). At $x = 0$, $x < 3$ so you use $y = -x$.

Comment: Got it. So that f(0)=0 is the key, whatever functions satisfies this will always be the answer?

Comment: Thank you both for the direction!!

Comment: That’s a hint for solving the question easily, since you immediately eliminate two choices. It might not necessarily be correct. You have to check the other two points. (In this case, it is correct though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From inspection, it is clear the graph passes through $(0, 0)$, the origin. Neither $y = \vert 3x-3\vert$ nor $y = \vert3x-1\vert$ satisfy this.

Looking at option $(B)$, at $x = 0$, you have $x < 3$, so $y = -x$, meaning $y = 0$. Hence, $(B)$ satisfies this condition. Checking the other two points, you can see both $(3, -3)$ and $(6, 0)$ satisfy $y = x-6$ (because $x \geq 3$). Hence, option $(B)$ is correct.

This function is known known as a “piecewise function” since the function contains two “sub-functions” which apply for a certain part of the domain. If $x \geq 3$, you have a different function than if $x < 3$ (and they’re independent of each other). The absolute value function is a piecewise function because $\vert x\vert = x$ if $x \geq 0$ and $\vert x\vert = -x$ if $x < 0$, and option $(B)$’s function is actually the absolute value function $y = \vert x-3\vert -3$ but it’s written as two separate functions.

$$x\geq 3 \implies x-3 \geq 0 \implies y = x-3-3 \implies y = x-6$$

$$x < 3 \implies x-3 < 0 \implies y = -(x-3)-3 \implies y = -x+3-3 \implies y = -x$$

Comment: +1 for awesomeness!